# Trying to select preceding zeros of a number present in a RQL query using regex

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to remove the preceding zeros of numbers present in below query

```
String query = "or(contains(number,'04506'),contains(name,'04506'),contains(vendorInfo.name,'04506'),contains(vendorInfo.number,'04506'),contains(costCategories.name,'04506')";
```

I'm using below regex

```
query = query.replaceAll("\\b0+","");
```

Problem is, it also removes zero, if we provide a query with a timestamp to it, e.g.

```
query = "ge(dateCreated,'2013-01-18T19:30:00.000Z')";
```

Comment: You could write it like this `(?<!\\S)0+`

Comment: So, you want to avoid replacing `0`s in the datetime values only? Or you want to remove `0`s in the `'<digits>'` like strings? Try `query = query.replaceAll("'0+(\\d+')","'$1"); `

Comment: No I only want to replace preceding zeros of number present under ''.  problem with my regex is, it also changes preceding zero after decimal point in timestamp

Comment: Then you can use `query = query.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\d\\.)0+","");`. Or `query = query.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\d\\.)0+(?=\\d)","");`. You should provide expected result in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds to not remove the zero followed by or preceded by any of `-`, `:`, `.` or `T`.

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String query = "contains(costCategories.name,'05.04506')ge(dateCreated,'2013-01-18T09:30:00.000Z')";
        query = query.replaceAll("(?<![-:\\.T])\\b0+(?![-:\\.T])", "");
        System.out.println(query);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
contains(costCategories.name,'5.04506')ge(dateCreated,'2013-01-18T09:30:00.000Z')
```